# connecting to DynamoDb from ec2 php file

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to dynamoDB. I am trying to connect to Dynamodb from a php file (index.php) running on my ec2 instance. I try the following code but it doesnot work. Any help will be appreciated

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;


$client = new DynamoDbClient([
  'region'  => 'us-east-1',
  'credentials' =>[
    'key'    => '#############',
    'secret' => '########',
],
    'version' => 'latest'
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be to create a role with permission to access dynamodb and attach it to ec2 instance.